# Create Custom Marker using markerwithlabel -Googlemap

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I want to make custom marker like below image,I am using advance marker in google map but that future in beta version and also not working with cluster of marker.

so,i am using markerwithlabel for creating marker

Like,

```
var marker = {};
    marker = new markerWithLabel.MarkerWithLabel({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat($careMapMarkerPins[i].lat), parseFloat($careMapMarkerPins[i].longt)),
        map: gm_map,
        title: $careMapMarkerPins[i].patient_name,
        channel_id: $careMapMarkerPins[i].id,
        icon: pinIcon,
        labelContent: $careMapMarkerPins[i].patient_name,
        labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(-30, 0),
        labelClass: "map-marker-label map-marker-label-" + channelStatus, // the CSS class for the label
        labelInBackground: true,
        d_latitude: parseFloat($careMapMarkerPins[i].lat),
        d_longitude: parseFloat($careMapMarkerPins[i].longt),
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
        return function () {
            getMarkerInfoFn(marker.channel_id);
        }
    })(marker, i));
```

using this code, i am creating marker but label not comming in center according to text. so,please help me out.

**Sorry for my Poor English.Please help me out,I apologize in advance for some mistake in asking question.**

[image]

Comment: Do you know you can loop over your JSON object ? just loop, compare your `from` and `to`, then calculate. It's really an easy thing to achieve.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel - calculate total amount according to json array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70080337/laravel-calculate-total-amount-according-to-json-array)